# data passing between component and page in next js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a index page with

```
getServerSideProps(){
//I am doing two api call
api1()
api2()
return{
props:{data:gotDataApi1, data2:gotDataApi2}
}
}
```

And I am passing to the component present inside index page

```
<component1 gotData1={gotDataApi1} gotData2={gotDataApi2}/>
```

it is working properly.

Now I have a component, which provides the parameters (on user interaction) to call the next required api. In the component control, I have added a Link and passed the user values

```
<Link 
  href={`indexpage?paths=${parameter1}/${parameter2}/${parameter3}`}>
</Link>
```

And received these parameters in getServerSideProps(context), and used to call another api
the call is hapening but some time giving the error split undefined

```
const {params, req, res, query} = context;
var str = query.paths;
cosole.log(str); // the output is 2022/1/1001
const splitStrings = await str.split("/ ");
```

the split value I am passing to api like bellow

This is the api3() call
const response4 = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/${splitStrings[0]}/${splitStrings[1]}/${splitStrings[2]}`);
const data4 = await response4.json();

this I want to replace to

```
<component1 gotData1={gotDataApi1} gotData3={gotDataApi3}/>
```

I created a [...slug].js page but here also I have to render my whole component like this, and index page is contains the sidemenu also, that code also I have to write here

```
<Side years={data2} chapters={data3} />
<component1 gotData1={gotDataApi1} gotData3={gotDataApi3}/>
```

the [...slug].js page also looks similar to my indexpage.

How I can solve this challenge.
Do I have to use useEffect to call the api3 and fill the values to component1. Instead of creating the [...slug] page.  Or is there any standard ways to operate this kind of challenge.

kindly do the needful.

Comment: Got the answer one of my friend helped                                                                                   
 let sampleArray =[];                                                                                               if(query.paths){
    var str = query.paths;
    const splitStrings = str.split("/");
    const response4 = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/${splitStrings[0]}/${splitStrings[1]}/${splitStrings[2]}`);
    sampleArray = await response4.json();
  }

Comment: `str.split` does not return a promise, you should not `await` it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer one of my friend helped

```
let sampleArray =[];                                                                                                if(query.paths){
    var str = query.paths;
    const splitStrings = str.split("/");
    const response4 = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/${splitStrings[0]}/${splitStrings[1]}/${splitStrings[2]}`);
    sampleArray = await response4.json();
    }                                                                                                                                           
    const finalData = sampleArray.length >0 ? sampleArray : data1;
```

I could able to pass the data to index page, instead of creating a [...slug] page